# Project released but not showing updated version in AppStore

Tags: deployment, app-store

My App is approved, but the updated version is not showing in the AppStore and in iTunes. It is still showing previous version(1.1). Can any one knows why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced the same issue recently..

I requested the apple to fix my issue.

i received the responce as follows

However, as you've discovered, this process can sometimes take up to 24 hours to fully take effect. As such, I thank you for your patience.